# How to retrieve values from Result set and use it for calculations

Tags: java, database, cucumber, resultset

I am using cucumber with Java and I want to calculate the tax. To do so I am connecting to data base and fetching the Gross Amount from data base.
Below are the Gross pension values which result set has returned

```
248.36, 125.36,452.36,578.35,456.77,
```

But now tax is getting calculated only for last value i.e, 456.77.I want to calculate tax for all the values. How do I do it? Below is the code which I have tried

```
while(rs.next()) {
    //To retrieve the first column
    GrossPension = rs.getFloat("GrossPension");             
    log.info("GrossPension is :" +GrossPension);
    float tax = this.GrossPension/5;        
    System.out.println("Tax is: "+tax);     
}
```

`GrossPension = rs.getFloat("GrossPension");` has retrieved values 248.36, 125.36, 452.36, 578.35, 456.77

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it as follows:

```
List<Float> grossPensionList = new ArrayList<Float>();
float grossPension;
while(rs.next()) {
    //To retrieve the first column
    grossPension = rs.getFloat("GrossPension");             
    log.info("GrossPension is :" +grossPension);
    grossPensionList.add(grossPension/5);        
 }

for (float tax: grossPensionList){
    System.out.println(tax);
}
```

The logic is to add gross pension retrieved from each row to a list and display the list once all the rows are read.

Comment: Thanks a lot.This is working.I have one more scenario.Now I have to compare this tax with the value in the UI.how do i compare this tax values with those values in  the UI?

Comment: Thank you.I have one more calculations i.e (netPaid=grossPension - tax).I tried to follow the same logic i.e using list.But I m getting some error saying tax is undefined. TaxList.add(grossPension-tax);

Comment: i cannot use if(grossPensionList.contains(the-value-from-ui)){//perform your logic}. as grossPensionList(Ex: 49.62) and the-value-from-ui (Ex:49.723) contain float values.So at that time it will fail

Comment: ya i tried that .But some values are 199.04001, 610.72,122.12,12.900001.I want to trim only 2 decimal places like 199.04, 610.72, 122.12,12.90.I used this (Math.round(NetPay)*100.0/100.0);.But after round off getting values as 199.0,611.0,122.0.Please help. i am new to java and selenium

Comment: if(grossPensionList.contains(the-value-from-ui)){//perform your logic}.In this i have 177.25,175,258,258 in grossPensionList and employee ids are(1,2,3,4).Now the ui value is 258 for employee id 4 It will match the 3rd element . I want to match UI values against employee id as well

Comment: Ya.grosspensionList can contain duplicate values.suppose i have 200,400,198,300 in Grosspension list and UI values are 200,400,200,300.But when comparing 3rd ui value(200) with Grosspensionlist.It will match with first element 200.and it returns true.But i want to compare 3rd element of UI with 3rd element of Gross pension only.            Note : UI values are not stored in list

Comment: ui values are not stored in list.scenario is i have 10 employees,i will search employee by employee id in ui and then for each employee i have to compare value of income tax on the ui with value in the grossPensionList. Bit complicated scenario