# How to check if value is present in list in java

Tags: java, list, selenium, contains

I want to match this Value  199.04 in TaxList. Below is my code

```
List<BigDecimal> TaxList = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();   

String NetP=driver.findElement(getNetPension).getAttribute("value");
float NetPension = new Float(NetP);
log.info("Value of Net Pension on screen : "+ NetPension);

if(TaxList.contains(NetPension)) 
{   
     log.info("Income tax value from the database is matching with the value on the screen");
}
else 
{
     log.warn("Both the values are different.Net pension is:" +NetPension );
}
```

I am printing the TaxList in console

[199.04, 610.72, 122.12, 866.52, 94.56, 143.48, 78.28, 132.6, 12.9, 32.03, 1797.38, 128.14, 724.94].
even though value 199.04 is present.it goes to else part

Both the values are different.Net pension is:199.04

Comment: what type is that NetPension? does that class implement equals and hashcode/comparable? you should consider following naming conventions, it would make your code a lot easier to read.

Comment: A `List<BigDecimal>` will never contain any `float`. Cast one or the other

Comment: ya changed converted float value into bigdecimal and it worked.Thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling the contains method on an ArrayList, it performs an `equals()` call on all contained elements. What could be happening here, is that instances of the class BigDecimal are not correctly compared to values of the float type.

Consider stepping into the `contains()` and check what is done with the float value when being compared to BigDecimal.
Another possible solution would be to convert the float value to a BigDecimal by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I believe, it is related to [How to retrieve values from Result set and use it for calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59158463/how-to-retrieve-values-from-result-set-and-use-it-for-calculations/59159330#comment104626991_59159330)

Instead of storing the `BigDecimal` to the list, store the `double` values rounded off up to 2 places which will make your processing easier. Given below is an example program:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Double> taxList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        taxList.add(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(610.72123)).setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue());
        taxList.add(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(122.0072123)).setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue());
        taxList.add(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(199.04123)).setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue());
        taxList.add(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(78.28123)).setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue());
        taxList.add(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(724.94507)).setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue());
        System.out.println(taxList);

        float f = 199.04f;
        double netPension = BigDecimal.valueOf(f).setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
        System.out.println(netPension);

        if (taxList.contains(netPension)) {
            System.out.println("Income tax value from the database is matching with the value on the screen");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Both the values are different. Net pension is:" + netPension);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[610.72, 122.01, 199.04, 78.28, 724.95]
199.04
Income tax value from the database is matching with the value on the screen
```

Answer (score 1):

cast NetPension in BigDecimal :

```
    List<BigDecimal> TaxList = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();   

    TaxList.add(new BigDecimal(584.32));
    TaxList.add(new BigDecimal(199.04));
    TaxList.add(new BigDecimal(201.66));

    double NetPension = 199.04;

    System.out.println("Value of Net Pension on screen : "+ NetPension);

    if(TaxList.contains(new BigDecimal(NetPension))) 
    {   
        System.out.println("Income tax value from the database is matching with the value on the screen");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Both the values are different.Net pension is:" +NetPension );
    }
```

output :

*Value of Net Pension on screen : 199.04*

*Income tax value from the database is matching with the value on the screen*